# Adding spinner dynamically in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I want to add my custom items, such as **Spinner**, in **Dialog** dynamically, but it not getting displayed. I suppose the spinner item is not getting accessed by `findviewbyid()`.
I am not getting any error but items are not getting displayed dynamycally.

Please suggest a method to do so.

**Here is my class and xml file:**

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

    Spinner spin;
    spin = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Material 1");
    list.add("Material 2");
    list.add("Material 3");
    list.add("Material 4");
    list.add("Material 5");
    list.add("Material 6");

    //Second List
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add("Mat 7");
    list2.add("Mat 8");
    list2.add("Mat 9");

    //Combined List
    List<String> listCombine = new ArrayList<String>();
    listCombine.addAll(list);
    listCombine.addAll(list2);

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listCombine); 

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spin.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    builder
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null))
           .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

**My xml file is:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Materials"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#FFB2B2"      
     />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Weight"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="55"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of inflating a second layout here:

```
builder
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null)) // Second layout!
```

Simply use the layout that you already inflated and set up:

```
builder
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setView(view) // Existing layout
```